# How to Terminate a never ending Task in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I am programming a very simple game in WPF Canvas - objects are moved in async Task by rendering the ellipse away by 1 pixel every 17 miliseconds - that is how I managed a ellipse to move. I even handled a collision with other objects - it just changes the direction. But the real problem is, that i can't handle Game Over, because the Task cannot be canceled, according to my research on stackoverflow. I can show a MessageBox if the ellipse went out of screen, but after clicking OK it just continues to do this async loop. Is there any way to make it stop?

```
async Task MoveStart()
    {
        double rozdiel = car.ActualWidth - snowball.ActualWidth;
        Back:
        while(crashed == false)
        {
            while(rightEl > 20)
            {
                topEl += 1;
                rightEl -= 0.5;
                leftEl += 0.5;
                botEl -= 1;
                Canvas.SetTop(snowball, topEl);
                Canvas.SetLeft(snowball, leftEl);
                if (botEl == botpixel + car.Height && leftpixel <= leftEl + snowball.ActualWidth && rightpixel <= rightEl + snowball.ActualHeight)
                {
                    body++;
                    textBlock1.Text = "Points: " + body + "\nHealth: " + zdravie;
                    crashed = true;
                    goto Crashed;
                }
                if(botEl == 0)
                {
                    zdravie--;
                    textBlock1.Text = "Points: " + body + "\nHealth: " + zdravie;
                    MessageBox.Show("Game over");
                }
                await Task.Delay(17);
            }
        }
        Crashed:
        while(crashed)
        {
            while (topEl > 50)
            {
                topEl -= 1;
                rightEl -= 0.5;
                leftEl += 0.5;
                botEl += 1;
                Canvas.SetTop(snowball, topEl);
                Canvas.SetLeft(snowball, leftEl);
                if (topEl == 50)
                { 
                    crashed = false;
                    goto Back;
                }
                await Task.Delay(17);
            }
        }
    }
```

those doubles rightEl, leftEl... are margins of canvas
I call the Task from simple async void

```
public async void Ready()
    {
        await MoveStart();
    }
```

And this Ready() void i call from MainWindow, because MainWindow cannot be async

Comment: `goto`?  Haven't seen that in a very loooooooooooooonnnngggg time....

Comment: What happens when you call 'Application.Current.Shutdown();' ?

Comment: don't put everything in one method. instead of `goto crashed` call another method. and return instead of `goto Back;`

Comment: @Musters application shuts down